# Where is my 800MB of RAM gone? Ubuntu is not detecting all my memory

Tags: ram, settings

I am a bit confused about my 800mb out of 2gb ram gone ?
I already test the following command,

```
 sudo dmidecode | grep Size | grep MB
```

> Size: 2048 Mar

```
free -h
```

| Type | total | used | free | shared | buff/cache | available |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mem | 1.2Gi | 564ML | 87Mi | 115Mi | 563Mi | 387Mi |
| Swap | 2.0Gi | 118Mi | 1.9Gi |  |  |  |

```
cat /proc/meminfo | grep Slab
```

> Stab: 114756 kB

```
dmesg | grep stolen
```

> 25.169226] pci 0000:00:00.0: detected 32768K stolen memory

```
sudo dmesg | grep -i 'Memory:'
```

```
[0.000000] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory

[mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff]

0.000000] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x0009f000-0x0009ffff]

[ 0.000000] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x000a0000-0x000eefff] [ 0.000000] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x000ef000-0x000fffff]

[ 0.000000] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x4ff4a000-0x76685fff]

[ 0.000000] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x76686000-0x76785fff]

[ 0.000000] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory [mem 0x76786000-0x777fefff]

[ 0.000000] Memory: 1172084K/1309604K available (16393K kernel code, 4374K rwdata, 10792K rodata, 3228K init, 6580K bss, 137260K reserved, OK

cma-reserved)

[ 0.025754] Freeing SMP alternatives memory: 40K

[ 0.955369] Freeing initrd memory: 63764K

[ 3.063509] Freeing unused decrypted mory: 2036K

[ 3.064575] Freeing unused kernel image (initmem) memory: 3228K

[ 3.065843] Freeing unused kernel image (text/rodata gap) memory: 2036K

[ 3.066450] Freeing unused kernel image (rodata/data gap) memory: 1496K
```

```
free -k; vmstats | head -n 1
```

| Type | total | used | free | shared | buff/cache | available |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mem | 1244944 | 732640 | 123252 | 67472 | 389052 | 288164 |
| Swap | 2097148 | 502332 | 1594816 |  |  |  |

```
 1244944 K total memory


sudo lshw -c video
```

```
*-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 02
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:30 memory:90000000-903fffff memory:80000000-8fffffff ioport:5060(size=8) memory:c0000-dffff
```

**and my graphics driver is using 256mb of ram and I have BIOS**
Here is the screenshot of my sysytem monitor,
[image]

I also had tested the memtest and it is showing 1.2 gb of ram only.
I also had ubuntu 22.04lts long side with ubuntu 20.04Lts and when I compare ram given in settings>about of 20.04Lts it shows 1.2 gb but in 22.04lts it shows 2gb.
I also searched whole askubuntu about this and didn't found anything about my problem.
If you want any other information know me in the comments.
Please give me the solution of it because I cant do anything on 1.2gb ram instead of 2gb ram.
***I also want to say that earlier it shows 1.9 gb insted of 1.2 gb which is now.***

Comment: Please edit your question adding output from `sudo dmesg  | grep -i 'Memory:'` and `free -k ; vmstat -s | head -n 1`.

Comment: Thanks,for fast reply.I will edit it in 2 minutes.

Comment: Please don't put screenshots of the terminal in this site. Always copy the content of the terminal as text and paste it directly in your question. Then format the pasted text as `code` using the {_} icon above the edit question window.

Comment: See this [Meta question and answers](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8713/why-do-people-post-screenshots-of-their-terminals).

Comment: I am sorry for that.I will edit it now.

Comment: What video hardware/drivers are you using? Maybe your video card is "stealing" memory? What UEFI/BIOS settings might apply to sharing memory?

Comment: Feystray, we don't know if you don't tell us the hardware.  Please list as many relevant facts about the hardware as you can including motherboard and GPU

Answer (score 2):

Integrated GPU uses system RAM. This is normal.

So your 800 MB are used by the Intel GPU.

Comment: Can I reduce it?

Comment: It depends on BIOS if there is a setting there.

Comment: I cant find any settings

Comment: Then you can't do anything. It is not related to OS. OS uses as much RAM as it is available.

Comment: But it is 1.9gb earlier and recently after booting up I realized some slowness and found that it is only detecting 1.2 out of 2gb

Comment: @Feystray If your GPU is an integrated graphics card that does NOT have dedicated graphics ram on it, then it will reserve a portion of the RAM (800MB is NOT unheard of) for the graphics, and that's reserved by the BIOS and firmware on your system for the GPU.  Your only options would be to upgrade your RAM in the system to a higher capacity if the BIOS doesn't have any options to change the Intel GPU's allotment of RAM away from general system use and to the GPU.